# Using PHP empty() file link gets set to null if field is empty

Tags: php, file-upload, string

I have an edit form that allows user to update a title and a file. If user leaves the file field blank then the url gets deleted from my sql table. I am using the empty() function to direct the script to one of two parts. One where the file url is updated and one where it is not. Not only does this not work but it also seems like an incorrect way of accomplishing this. If a user leaves the file input field empty I would like the url already stored in the sql table to NOT get updated. Any suggestion - thank you in advance!

**HTML**

```
<form name="edit_date" class="data-form" method="POST" id="edit_list_data" enctype="multipart/form-data>
<input  class="fileUpload" name="flyer" type="file"  />
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    //if file field empty just update title
    if (empty($_FILES['flyer']['name'])) 
    {
        require('../dbcon2.php');
        try 
        {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE listings SET title = :title WHERE id = :id");
            //Bind
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); 
            $stmt->execute();
            $response = array
                 ('state'  => 200, "success" => true, "id" => $_POST['id'], "titlea" => $_POST['title'] 
                 );
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            $data = array("success" => false, "sentence" => $sql, "error" => $e->getMessage());
            exit(json_encode($data));
        }
    }
    //if file field not empty update it and title
    else 
    {
        $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
        $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
        $extensionf = end($tempf);
        if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf") && ($_FILES["flyer"]["size"] < 524288000) && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
        {   
            if ($_FILES["flyer"]["error"] > 0) 
            {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["flyer"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }   
            else 
            {
                if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
                {
                    unlink("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                }
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);             
                $ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
            }
        }
    }
    require('../dbcon2.php');
    try 
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE listings SET title = :title, ad_link = :ad_link WHERE id = :id");
        //Bind
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':ad_link', $ad_link);
        $stmt->execute();
        $response = array
             ('state'  => 200, "success" => true, "id" => $_POST['id'], "ad_linka" => $ad_link, 
             );
        echo json_encode($response);  
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $data = array("success" => false, "sentence" => $sql, "error" => $e->getMessage());
        exit(json_encode($data));
    }     
?>
```

Comment: now that your code is looking prettier, looks like the second try/catch block is misplaced. shouldn't you place that part right after `$ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];` ? PS: too many redundant code here btw.

Comment: @OzgurBar thank you for the edit. I can actually read it now :) so i think the try catch is situated correctly, the basic scheme here is if empty(file) {just change title} else {change title and file}

Comment: @OI was thinking that maybe the function is not seeing the field because ($_FILES['flyer']['name']) is not the correct variable reference?

Comment: could you also provide the <form> tag? What exactly is the problem here? I was wondering if you are missing enctype attribute of form element.

Comment: I'm using ajax. so the from action isn't filled. Problem is if a user doesn't select a file to upload (leaves it blank on my edit form, it deletes the current file link from sql ($ad_link). I would like that to not happen, if user leaves file input blank then sql saves the current link already there

Comment: But the second try/catch block is running in both cases and you're updating the link in that one?

Comment: The second try/catch should only run in the second instance, only run for else{} if the file field is not empty

Comment: most poeple I'm finding use isset for something like this but I've been unable to figure out how to use it

Comment: can you check out the answer and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The second try/catch should only run in the second instance, only run
>   for else{} if the file field is not empty

But this part of the code is running regardless of `if/else` block. thus, overriding the field `ad_link` in table. See: `UPDATE listings SET title = :title, ad_link = :ad_link WHERE id = :id`

Simply place the code below after `$ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];`

```
require('../dbcon2.php');
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE listings SET title = :title, ad_link = :ad_link WHERE id = :id");
    //Bind
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':ad_link', $ad_link);
    $stmt->execute();
    $response = array
         ('state'  => 200, "success" => true, "id" => $_POST['id'], "ad_linka" => $ad_link, 
         );
    echo json_encode($response);  
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $data = array("success" => false, "sentence" => $sql, "error" => $e->getMessage());
    exit(json_encode($data));
}
```

Full code should be like this

```
//if file field empty just update title
if (empty($_FILES['flyer']['name'])) 
{
    require('../dbcon2.php');
    try 
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE listings SET title = :title WHERE id = :id");
        //Bind
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $response = array
             ('state'  => 200, "success" => true, "id" => $_POST['id'], "titlea" => $_POST['title'] 
             );
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $data = array("success" => false, "sentence" => $sql, "error" => $e->getMessage());
        exit(json_encode($data));
    }
}
//if file field not empty update it and title
else 
{
    $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
    $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
    $extensionf = end($tempf);
    if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf") && ($_FILES["flyer"]["size"] < 524288000) && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
    {   
        if ($_FILES["flyer"]["error"] > 0) 
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["flyer"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }   
        else 
        {
            if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
            {
                unlink("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
            }
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);             
            $ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];

            //Moved here - Starts
            require('../dbcon2.php');
            try 
            {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE listings SET title = :title, ad_link = :ad_link WHERE id = :id");
                //Bind
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':ad_link', $ad_link);
                $stmt->execute();
                $response = array
                     ('state'  => 200, "success" => true, "id" => $_POST['id'], "ad_linka" => $ad_link, 
                     );
                echo json_encode($response);  
            }
            catch (Exception $e) 
            {
                $data = array("success" => false, "sentence" => $sql, "error" => $e->getMessage());
                exit(json_encode($data));
            }     

            //Moved here - Ends
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry about that i had to step out of office. So i put this in and it's running the else portion of the code (starting around line 27) if a file is uploaded. If a file is not chosen (left blank) however the part after the if statement (lines 3-24) are not being executed if the file is left blank

Comment: And what do you see when you `echo $_FILES['flyer']['name'];`?